# Creating token list from mysql query into json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, twitter-typeahead

i have recently started using the twitter typeahead addon for a new project and have hit a bit of a snag, i am querying 2 columns in 1 table for the data to search, i have it working fine when just searching 1 column however when moving to two i believe i need to start using tokens for the search.

however i cant figure out a way to add in tokens into my array to then encode them to json and return back to the search

this is my code so far:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', '');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT NAME, CLID FROM customer');
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['NAME'] = $row['NAME'];
    $row_array['CLID'] = $row['CLID'];
    $row_array['tokens'] = "";
    $results[] = $row_array;
}

$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
return $json;
```

the tokens line is going into the array fine however im not sure on how to format it, i understand it needs to be in the format of

```
tokens:[
"token1", "token2", "token3"
]
```

the tokens will be the values of the NAME and CLID, how can i go about creating the tokens to ideally look like this:

```
{
name: "name",
CLID: "CLID",
tokens: [
"name1", "clid1", "name2", "clid2", "name3", "clid3"...
]
}
```

Comment: did you try: $row_array['tokens'] = $row["NAME"]; $row_array['tokens'] = $row["CLID"];

Comment: yes i have tried this, however it only returns one set of tokens, for example:
[{"NAME":"maintest","CLID":"02147483647","tokens":"02147483647"}]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out by reading up some more, to create a nested json element you need to add in through an array within an arry

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['NAME'] = $row['NAME'];
    $row_array['CLID'] = $row['CLID'];
    $row_array['tokens'] = array($row["NAME"],$row["CLID"]); //create new array and add the tokens you want
    $results[] = $row_array;
}
```